# Is there an R function to create graphics to visualize comparative percentages?

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to create a graphic like this: any ideas?[image: showcasing the relationship between 2 sets of percentages]

Comment: I would use a Javascript library.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any suggestions for where to start with finding a good javascript library to do something like this?